# Algorithm to obtain the null matrix from a series of predefined operators

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, algorithms, modular-arithmetic

Consider a matrix $\tilde A$ of size $(N+2)\times (N+2)$ whose coefficients are either $0$ or $1$.

Denote $A$ the submatrix containing columns from 2 to $N$ of $\tilde A$
and line from $2$ to $N$ of $\tilde A$.
In short $A=\tilde A(2...N,2...N)$.

Define the following elementary operator:
$$b_i^j(A) = A + E_{i,j}+ E_{i,j+1}+ E_{i+1,j}+ E_{i-1,j}+ E_{i,j-1} \quad \text{mod}\; [2]$$
for all $i,j$ of $\mathbf{\{1,\ldots, N\}}$ where $E_{a,b}$ is the elementary matrix (which has 0 everywhere except for the coefficient in position $(a,b)$).

Is it possible to transform any submatrix $M\in M_{N,N}(\{0,1\})$ of a matrix $\tilde M\in M_{N+2,N+2}(\{0,1\})$  to the null matrix of $M_{N,N}(\{0,1\})$  using these operations $b_i^j$ ?

***Remark***: Assuming the existence of such algorithm and applying it to the matrix $\tilde M$, we obtain a matrix denoted as $\tilde M_{\infty}$. We do not care about the coefficients of the first and last columns/lines of $\tilde M_{\infty}$, we only care that the submatrix $M_{\infty}=\tilde M_{\infty}(2...N,2...N)$ is null.

Comment: Do you really want to reduce anything modulo $2 \pi$ ? That's a fairly foreign object in the algebraic setting in which the rest of your problem is happening. (Most likely, it changes nothing, since $\pi$ is rational and so the fractional part of your entries will give away how often you have added $2 \pi$...)

Comment: On the other hand, if your "$\mod 2\pi$" is meant to be a "$\mod 2$", then you are studying "button madness" (aka "lights-out") on a square board, and this has seen some research (at least on a torus: https://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/ca/madness/mad.html ).

Comment: indeed, it's mod 2 .... yeah I would like to solve the button madness? I didn't expect it was so complicated

Comment: The link doesn't study the same problem that you are studying (as the link works with a toroidal grid), so maybe yours is actually simpler.